# What is the equivalent of a static cursor in postgres

Tags: postgresql

A STATIC CURSOR in MSSQL will create a temporary table with the selected data and use that.

Is there an equivalent way to do this in postgres? What happens when a row you've selected in the cursor gets deleted in the underlying table prior to the cursor reaching it?

Comment: A statement has a consistent view of the underlying tables as they were at the moment when the statement started, regardless on what happened to the table(s) after the statement started. I don't think this is any different for cursors.

Comment: In addition to that: if you are looking for a cursor that can survive a commit, use a `WITH HOLD` cursor.